# Organized or co-organized?

Tags: conference, workshop

I organized a couple of workshops, as in I was the correspondent person, and I designed the workshop, invited others to co-organize with me, was the lead editor to proceedings etc. But I feel awkward when I say "I organized", as eventually there was a board of organizers.

Should I say "I organized" or "co-organized"? Is there a right way to do this? Is it vain to say I organized? On the other hand, if I am invited to take part in the organizing board, I say "I co-organized" and mostly I also indicate in which board, which responsibilities/tasks/roles I have taken on in an attempt to make it clear that I wasn't the lead organizer.

Comment: "I chaired", "I was the chair"?

Comment: “I was an organizer of the ABC conference.”

Comment: How about "I helped organize". Also, as  a math person, can't help thinking that "co-organize" is the _dual_ of "organize"...

Comment: I can't figure the context.  Is this over drinks at a bar, on a CV, in an annual report to your department?  You would phrase it differently in different contexts.

Comment: @paulgarrett So their adjoint organized the co-workshop?

Comment: @JeffE, assuming existence, and up to unique something...

Comment: @TerryLoring CV and bio

Comment: well, co-author is not the dual of "author", I was thinking it would be a similar term, I like "helped organize" though, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are other, more specific, possibilities. "I led the organization of ...", or something similar. "I was the lead organizer and editor of...". On the other side, "I aided in the organization of...".

Don't make it a title, but a description, unless the organization requires titles.

Comment: And if a title is needed, "Organizer" seems fine and doesn't signal that you're the only one, there can always be multiple of them.